# How to solve this possible scenario with DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to develop a possible DynamoDB table with the following problem:

1 - The client comes and say - "Hey, when I click in a product in the product list, I want to see all information about the product, including the factory address which produces it"

2 - The client also wants to update the address of the factory when it is necessary.

How would you draw this table? would you add the full address of the factory in every single product item?

My main concern is amount of queries I will have to run.

If I put the products in one table, and the factories in another table, I would have to call 2 queries to bring all the information the client wants

If I add the factory address in the product item, I would have to update multiple lines in case the factory address is changed.

I would like to have a way where I have to update only one item to update the address of the factory and also run only one query to get all the product information + factory address.

Is it even possible or only in a relational database?

Comment: Put it in two tables if that’s simplest for you. If your application backend is running in AWS, then getting a single, small item from the factory table will add less than 10ms of latency to the overall query. On top of that, (assuming the addresses of a factory change infrequently) you could also cache the addresses in memory.

Answer (score 1):

"If I add the factory address in the product item, I would have to update multiple lines in case the factory address is changed." <-- This is definitely not worth it. You may pay a lot in write capacity every time a factory address is updated.

I run a fairly complex app on DynamoDB and would create 2 tables for your scenario: Products table which has an attribute with a `FactoryID`, and a Factories table with `FactoryID` as the Hash key. In practice, I have found DynamoDB to be very fast with multiple lookups (which you could batch together, if appropriate), and I use this pattern frequently to "hydrate" products in my app with information from different tables.